# Using a dictionary entry as a variable in a shell command?

Tags: python, list, shell, dictionary, variables

For my first real project I'm using Tkinter to create a UI where, when a button is pressed, something happens.

I've created the UI which works well - buttons are made and are clickable, but I want each button to have it's own unique function - this is where I get lost.

I've got a nested dictionary:

```
siteDict = {1: {'app1': 'explorer', 'app2': 'firefox', 'app3': 'google-chrome', 'app4': 'edge'},
            2: {'site1': 'http://www.google.com', 'site2': 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'site3': 'http://altavista', 'site4': 'http://www.askjeeves.com', }}
```

And I want to pass entries from the dictionary to terminal instead of having to manually define each one like I am now:

```
def Expl_Goog():
        os.system('echo Opening Explorer and navigating to Google (http://www.google.com). Please wait.')
```

So instead of doing `echo Opening Explorer and navigating to Google (http://www.google.com). Please wait.` is there a way to pass 2 items from my dictionary into the terminal command? {app1} and {site1} in this example.

Defining variables for ~12 things isn't terrible, but the real side of the project has the same type of dictionary but with 64 entries in each one.

Here's the code I have so far, which is functional. The button click functionality is done via the "command" argument within the button creation -  `ttk.Button(self.Explorer_labelFrame, text="google", command=Expl_Goog).grid(column=0, row=0, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)`

Built on 3.9.5

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os

# Dictionary to house variables
siteDict = {1: {'app1': 'explorer', 'app2': 'firefox', 'app3': 'google-chrome', 'app4': 'edge'},
            2: {'site1': 'http://www.google.com', 'site2': 'http://www.yahoo.com', 'site3': 'http://altavista', 'site4': 'http://www.askjeeves.com', }}

# Defining the action for the Tkinter button press to do
def Expl_Goog():
        os.system('echo Opening Explorer and navigating to Google (http://www.google.com). Please wait.')

# Another definition - Explorer and Yahoo
def Expl_Yah():
        os.system('echo Opening Explorer and navigating to Yahoo (http://www.yahoo.com). Please wait.')

def Fire_Goog():
        os.system('echo Opening Firefox and navigating to Google (http://www.google.com). Please wait.')

def Fire_Yah():
    os.system('echo Opening Firefox and navigating to Yahoo (http://www.yahoo.com). Please wait.')

# Build UI via Tkinter
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        self.title("Website Launcher")
        self.minsize(200, 400)
        #self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')
        self.lift()
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.update()

        self.Explorer_labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Explorer", labelanchor='n')
        self.Explorer_labelFrame.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=20, pady=40)
        
        self.Firefox_labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text="Firefox", labelanchor='n')
        self.Firefox_labelFrame.grid(column=2, row=7, padx=20, pady=40)


        self.labels_Explorer()
        self.labels_Firefox()

# Creating UI Buttons
# "command" argument makes clicking the button run the terminal command defined above
    def labels_Explorer(self):
        ttk.Button(self.Explorer_labelFrame, text="google", command=Expl_Goog).grid(column=0, row=0, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        ttk.Button(self.Explorer_labelFrame, text="yahoo", command=Expl_Yah).grid(column=0, row=1, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        ttk.Button(self.Explorer_labelFrame, text="altavista").grid(column=0, row=2, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        ttk.Button(self.Explorer_labelFrame, text="askjeeves").grid(column=0, row=3, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)

    def labels_Firefox(self):
        ttk.Button(self.Firefox_labelFrame, text="google", command=Fire_Goog).grid(column=0, row=0, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        ttk.Button(self.Firefox_labelFrame, text="yahoo", command=Fire_Yah).grid(column=0, row=1, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        ttk.Button(self.Firefox_labelFrame, text="altavista").grid(column=0, row=2, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)
        ttk.Button(self.Firefox_labelFrame, text="askjeeves").grid(column=0, row=3, pady=2, sticky=tk.EW)

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to do a *product* between apps and sites:

```py
from itertools import product

siteDict = {
    1: {
        "app1": "explorer",
        "app2": "firefox",
        "app3": "google-chrome",
        "app4": "edge",
    },
    2: {
        "site1": "http://www.google.com",
        "site2": "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "site3": "http://altavista",
        "site4": "http://www.askjeeves.com",
    },
}


for app, site in product(siteDict[1].values(), siteDict[2].values()):
    s = "echo Opening {app} and navigating to {site}. Please wait.".format(
        app=app, site=site
    )
    print(s)
```

Prints:

```
echo Opening explorer and navigating to http://www.google.com. Please wait.
echo Opening explorer and navigating to http://www.yahoo.com. Please wait.
echo Opening explorer and navigating to http://altavista. Please wait.
echo Opening explorer and navigating to http://www.askjeeves.com. Please wait.
echo Opening firefox and navigating to http://www.google.com. Please wait.
echo Opening firefox and navigating to http://www.yahoo.com. Please wait.
echo Opening firefox and navigating to http://altavista. Please wait.
echo Opening firefox and navigating to http://www.askjeeves.com. Please wait.
echo Opening google-chrome and navigating to http://www.google.com. Please wait.
echo Opening google-chrome and navigating to http://www.yahoo.com. Please wait.
echo Opening google-chrome and navigating to http://altavista. Please wait.
echo Opening google-chrome and navigating to http://www.askjeeves.com. Please wait.
echo Opening edge and navigating to http://www.google.com. Please wait.
echo Opening edge and navigating to http://www.yahoo.com. Please wait.
echo Opening edge and navigating to http://altavista. Please wait.
echo Opening edge and navigating to http://www.askjeeves.com. Please wait.
```

---

EDIT: To get only specific combination:

```py
siteDict = {
    1: {
        "app1": "explorer",
        "app2": "firefox",
        "app3": "google-chrome",
        "app4": "edge",
    },
    2: {
        "site1": "http://www.google.com",
        "site2": "http://www.yahoo.com",
        "site3": "http://altavista",
        "site4": "http://www.askjeeves.com",
    },
}


def get(a, b):
    s = "echo Opening {app} and navigating to {site}. Please wait."
    return s.format(
        app=siteDict[1]["app{}".format(a)], site=siteDict[2]["site{}".format(b)]
    )


print(get(1, 3))
```

Prints:

```
echo Opening explorer and navigating to http://altavista. Please wait.
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! So this does well to print every permutation but how would I incorporate it in regards to getting it to reference just the single variable? `print(s)` does everything but the problem I'm running in to is that I want to have a function that  can be called with parameters where the specified parameters is an item from the dictionary. So in the "command" parameter of the button I can just do something like `command=web(1,3)` where web is the function and 1=first dict first entry, 3=2nd dict 3rd entry (or something like that). Basically 1 button = 1 action that includes vars

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind pointing me in a direction on what to research for what I always asking for? Is this mostly just knowing how `.format` comes into play? I'm relatively new to Python and trying to learn what I can when I use it. Thanks again @andrej.

Comment: @Feanux Look at official documentation of `str.format`. Or https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp is a good resource.